# vb.net Nancy return HTML-Page

Tags: vb.net, nancy, self-hosting

Long story short:

I've got some C#-Code which shows me the file "hello.html" by default.

```
Get["/"] = parameters =>
{
  return View["hello", this.Request.Url];
};
```

Now i'd like to do the project with VB.NET and I tried to convert the Code but I get a Http-Erorrcode '500'

```
MyBase.Get("/") = Function(parameters)
   Return View("hello", Request.Url)
End Function
```

Edit:
I've to say that the C#-Code bases on the Nancy-Version 0.18.0.0
and the VB.net on 0.22.2.0.

I cant find any code in VB.Net on the internet. Has anyone any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a whole heap of resources on VB.NET from the Wiki:

https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Blog-Posts%2C-Video-%26-Audio#vbnet

To answer your question though.

The most basic example would be something like this:

```
Imports Nancy

Public Class HelloModule
    Inherits NancyModule

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.Get("/") = Function(parameters) "Hello World"
    End Sub

End Class
```

Just to return a string.

If that's working then it probably something to do with your view, or the parameter to the view.

Comment: I already went through this guide you posted. If you'd have read it you would agree that there's no example for returning a html-File.

I've no trouble with your Example you posted. This is working for me. 
The thing I'm looking for is returning a HTML-File, like in the C#-Code.

Comment: So you can confirm that the example above works. Great. So the problem is with your view, or view location, or parameter, or something else.

Comment: I guess it is but I cant find any documentation about it in VB.NET so I thought you guys could help me.

Comment: Are your views in a views folder? You dont need doco, its the same stuff, different syntax, you said the example code works, your project is setup, your views may not be in a views folder.

Comment: That could be it! I'll give it a try when I'm back home.

Comment: Ok, if that doesn't work I will write a quick working sample for you so you can compare to figure out what you're missing.

Comment: I created the folder "View" and created a file View\hello.html
It's still not working for me. No idea what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: The folder should be `Views`

Comment: Hah - it works! 
I just wonder why it works with C# where the folder is named "View".

I guess you solved the problem, thanks mate.

Comment: You don't have a convention in your site to have a 'view' folder do you? In the bootstrapper or something?